# Looking for a hard back coffee table book of the collected artwork from the Golden Age of Science Fiction through the early 1980s

Tags: story-identification, books

Please help me find a large hard back book that contained the collected artwork from all various types of science fiction art from the Golden Age of science fiction up through the early 1980s.

I used to own this book as a teenager and I'd like to purchase the book so that I can look through the art. There are two specific pieces of art that I remember from it:

- An humanoid alien with a big head, holding his ears as a spaceship flew by in the background.
- A striking piece of art where Jesus is hanging on the cross at Calvary, and there are several lizard-like aliens kneeling at the foot of the cross.

I owned the hard back book in the mid to late '80s in the USA. I cannot remember the name of the book or any of the artists in it, but do remember that there were write-ups about the art style of the various periods of sci-fi art over the decades. I also believe that the hard back book had a cover jacket that could be slid off.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Were the two paictures you described black and white or in color? Were they magazine covers, with visible logos, prices, titles?

Comment: There's a Jim Burns picture, [*Two Tales and Eight Tomorrows*](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/0/06/TWTLSNDGHT1976.jpg) (for the story "The Streets of Ashkelon") that has green humanoids at the foot of a cross with a Christ-like figure on it.  But the only art book it's _listed_ as appearing in ([*Aliens in Space: An Illustrated Guide to the Inhabited Galaxy*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?476424), one of Stephen Caldwell's *Galactic Encounters* series) actually has a cropped version that eliminates the cross.

Comment: David Kyle's *A Pictorial History of Science Fiction* is a coffee table sci-fi art book, but maybe too early (1976), and I don't know if the two pictures you describe are in it. https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?651301

Comment: Here are some updates: The pictures that I described were in color and not black & white. I don't recall that the pictures were magazine covers--I fairly confident that they didn't have visible logos, prices, or titles on them.

Comment: The picture that was shared on the Two Tales and Eight Tomorrows has similar artwork to the picture of Jesus on the cross that I remember, but I don't believe it's the exact picture. It could be the same artist, but I remember that Jesus on the cross was positioned in the center of the picture with the vantage point being closer to the cross and the aliens. I don't remember the picture having the viewer be so far away as the Two Tales and Eight tomorrows.

Comment: And I can't be certain but the cover for the "A Pictorial History of Science Fiction" doesn't look familiar to me. I wish there was a way that I could "look inside" the book to see some of the art and articles. That would help me remember. Thank you for taking the time and trying to help. I appreciate it!

Comment: @RonVitale If you go to the home page of the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi), enter "sf art book" (without quotation marks) in the search box, select "tag" from the drop-down menu, and click on "go", you will get a list of sf art books. In most cases, clicking on a title will get you a cover image. Maybe you will recognize the one you're looking for.

Comment: Was it an American or a British publication? Do you know if it was the work of one artist or various artists?

Comment: Thank you for the link for the Internet Speculative Fiction Database. I went through all the items listed there between the late '70s to the late '80s, but couldn't find a book that was the one that I was looking for. To answer another person's question: The hard back book was an American publication and it was the work of multiple artists. From what I can remember, it was a history of sci-fi art from the beginning of sci-fi up to the present day (mid-80s at that point). There were many colorful pictures in the book along with text that talked about the art of the time.